# INT 13 Extension Read in C

Tags: c, assembly, bios

i can use extended read functions of bios int 13h well from assembly,
with the below code

```
; *************************************************************************
        ; Setup DISK ADDRESS PACKET
        ; *************************************************************************

            jmp     strtRead

        DAPACK :
            db      010h                            ; Packet Size
            db      0                               ; Always 0
        blkcnt:
            dw      1                               ; Sectors Count
        db_add :
            dw      07e00h                          ; Transfer Offset
            dw      0                               ; Transfer Segment
        d_lba :
            dd      1                               ; Starting LBA(0 - n)
            dd      0                               ; Bios 48 bit LBA


            ; *************************************************************************
            ; Start Reading Sectors using INT13 Func 42
            ; *************************************************************************
        strtRead:

            mov     si, OFFSET DAPACK; Load DPACK offset to SI              
            mov     ah, 042h                        ; Function 42h
            mov     dl, 080h                        ; Drive ID
            int     013h; Call INT13h
```

i want to convert this to be a c callable function but i have no idea about how to transfer the parameters from c to asm like drive id , sectors count, buffer segment:offset .... etc.

i am using msvc and masm and working with nothing except bios functions.
can anyone help ?!!

update :
i have tried the below function but always nothing loaded into the buffer ??

```
void read_sector()
{
    static unsigned char currentMBR[512] = { 0 };
    struct disk_packet //needed for int13 42h
    {
        byte size_pack; //size of packet must be 16 or 16+
        byte reserved1; //reserved
        byte no_of_blocks; //nof blocks for transfer
        byte reserved2; //reserved
        word offset;    //offset address
        word segment; //segment address
        dword lba1;
        dword lba2;
    } disk_pack;

    disk_pack.size_pack = 16; //set size to 16
    disk_pack.no_of_blocks = 1; //1 block ie read one sector
    disk_pack.reserved1 = 0; //reserved word
    disk_pack.reserved2 = 0; //reserved word
    disk_pack.segment = 0; //segment of buffer
    disk_pack.offset = (word)&currentMBR[0]; //offset of buffer
    disk_pack.lba1 = 0; //lba first 32 bits
    disk_pack.lba2 = 0; //last 32 bit address

    _asm
    {
        mov dl, 080h;
        mov[disk_pack.segment], ds;     
        mov si, disk_pack;
        mov ah, 42h;
        int 13h
        ; jc    NoError; //No error, ignore error code
        ; mov   bError, ah; // Error, get the error code
        NoError:
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you looked at #pragma pack?  disk_packet may not be created the way you expect.  Also, is the carry flag set?  What value is returned in ah?

Comment: What's the memory model? You may want to try and make `disk_pack` static (like you already did with the buffer). That will locate the struct in the data segment instead of the stack segment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Beyond the lack of `#pragma pack(1)` potential issue (in this case you might be lucky that it aligns nicely) and the fact that `disk_pack` is on the stack(SS not DS), I'm curious what the target environment you are running it on is? DOS? Knowing the memory model  will help. You mention MASM and MSVC. Your MSVC must be old (1.52?) to compile 16 bit code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post this as "answer"; I want to post this as "comment" but it is too long...

Different compilers have a different syntax of inline assembly. This means that the correct syntax of the following lines:

```
    mov[disk_pack.segment], ds;     
    mov si, disk_pack;
```

... depends on the compiler used. Unfortunately I do not use 16-bit C compilers so I cannot help you in this point.

The next thing I see in your program is the following one:

```
disk_pack.segment = 0; //segment of buffer
disk_pack.offset = (word)&currentMBR[0]; //offset of buffer
```

With a 99% chance this will lead to a problem. Instead I would to the following:

```
struct disk_packet //needed for int13 42h
{
    byte size_pack;
    byte reserved;
    word no_of_blocks; // note that this is 16-bit!
    void far *data; // <- This line is the main change!
    dword lba1;
    dword lba2;
} disk_pack;

...

disk_pack.size_pack = 16;
disk_pack.no_of_blocks = 1;
disk_pack.reserved = 0;
disk_pack.data = &currentMBR[0]; // also note the change here
disk_pack.lba1 = 0;
disk_pack.lba2 = 0;
...
```

Note that some compilers name the keyword "_far" or "__far" instead of "far".

A third problem is that some (buggy) BIOSes require ES to be equal to the segment value from the disk_pack and a fourth one is that many compilers require the inline assembly code not to modify any registers (AX, CX and DX is normally OK).

These two could be solved the following way:

```
push ds;
push es;
push si;
mov dl, 080h;
// TODO here: Set ds:si to disk_pack in a compiler-specific way
mov es,[si+6];
mov ah, 42h;
int 13h;
...
pop si;
pop es;
pop ds;
```

In my opinion the "#pragma pack" should not be neccessary because all elements in the structure are propperly aligned.

Comment: It depends on the memory model being used. Using a 16 bit compiler and assembler of the day - if `ss == ds` then you could just do a straight `lea si, disk_pack` . If you are supporting models where `ss != ds` or `ss==ds` and you want to make it work - I'd create a temp variable like `void far *fdp = &disk_pack`; and do an `lds si, fdp;` before `mov es,[si+6];`. *LDS* instruction can take an m16:16.

Comment: `disk_pack.data = &currentMBR[0]` can simply be written as `disk_pack.data = currentMBR;` since *currentMBR* is itself a pointer to the first element already.

Comment: @MichaelPetch When using real-mode programs there are not many compilers available that you can use - many of them are not "up to date". I remember some compiler that did not allow implicit casing from an array to a pointer so `&(array[0])` had to be used. One very popular compiler that can generate real mode code is Watcom. At least under older Watcom versions the inline assembly cannot directly access variable names but you have to pass them in a special way. In GNU C (MingW, 32-bit) this is also the case so `lea si, disk_pack` would not work.

Comment: That is true, however one of the things I noted is that he did say he was using _MASM_ and _MSVC_  . His code did include `mov[disk_pack.segment], ds; ` so whatever he was using could reference C variables so I figure `lea si, disk_pack` would work equally well. I happened to find my old test VM this morning with MSVC 1.52c and Masm 6 and it does support _lea_ in this way. MSVC also seems to have no issue with `disk_pack.data = currentMBR`. I use to write such code in the good ole days with both and was pretty sure that compiler wasn't entirely brain dead.

Comment: GNU C/GAS I'll also agree you have to use a special way - assembler templates to access C variables and goto labels.